# Criando elementos com jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Como criar elementos com `jQuery`?

Vou tentar explicar...

Eu tenho 2 telas, *cadastro de cartões* e *visualização dos cartões*.

Para cada cartão cadastrado, eu envio para o servidor e faço a inserção no banco de dados interno. Até aí tudo bem.

Só que para cada cartão cadastrado, preciso, também, ir populando meu `html` de visualização de cartões.

Ele fica assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código da imagem acima é esse:

```
<div class="row corpo-cartoes">
            <div class="col s12 m7" style="width: 100%;">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-image">
                        <img src="img/apresentacao.jpg">
                        <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-action icone-meu-cartao">
                        <a href="#" ><i class="material-icons">code</i></a>

                        <a href="#"><i class="material-icons">crop_free</i></a>
                        <a href="#"><i class="material-icons">visibility</i></a>
                        <a href="#"><i class="material-icons btn-editar">edit</i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Minha dúvida é:

Como faço para criar o código acima com `jQuery` para ir populando na tela de visualização de cartões para cada cartão cadastrado?

Ou teria uma maneira melhor de fazer isso?

Comment: Com jQuery vc pode fazer: `$('#elementoAlvo').html('<p>Meu elemento</p>');` ou, considerando que terão vários "cards", pode fazer com `.appendTo()`, também do jQuery! Documentação: http://api.jquery.com/appendto/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma das opções é usando a tag `<template>` do HTML https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template

> O  elemento HTML `<template>` é um mecanismo para encapsular um conteúdo
>   do lado do cliente que não é renderizado quando a página é carregada,
>   mas que pode ser instanciado posteriormente em tempo de execução
>   usando JavaScript.

Essa é uma tag que não é visível para o usuário e dentro dela vc pode construir o seu bloco de código que será a base a ser duplicada. Depois com um `script` e chamando a função no `click` no elemento vc duplica e mostra o conteúdo que está dentro da tag `template` e mostra na página "plotando" o código dentro do `#container` que vc pode por e alinhar onde quiser na página. *(não precisa  jQuery nesse caso)*

Repare que é dentro da `<div id="container"></div>` que ele vai colocar o código que está dentro da tag `template`. Nesse caso vc nem precisa colocar `display:none` na tag, pois ela não renderiza na tela por *default*

Veja como fica, tem um Btn que quando vc clica adiciona o bloco do *template*, mas vc pode adaptar pra seu caso:

```js
function useIt() {
    var content = document.querySelector('template').content;
    document.querySelector('#container').appendChild(
    document.importNode(content, true));
}
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css" />



<div class="container" >
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="useIt()">Clique aqui</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row corpo-cartoes">
        <!-- onde vai plotar o template -->
        <div id="container"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- aqui etá o seu template com o bloco de código -->
<template>
    <div class="col s12 m7" style="width: 30%;">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-image">
                <img src="https://placecage.com/100/100">
                <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
            </div>
            <div class="card-action icone-meu-cartao">
                <a href="#" ><i class="material-icons">code</i></a>

                <a href="#"><i class="material-icons">crop_free</i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="material-icons">visibility</i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="material-icons btn-editar">edit</i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: MUITO bom! Muito obrigada!!

Comment: @Tfm que bom que ajudou! Eu não sou muito bom de JS, mas esse modelinho já me salvou uma vez. Boa sorte ai

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer em Js puro da seguinte forma

```
var content = "<div class='card'>Conteudo do card</div>";
document.getElementById('ID-CONTENT-DIV').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd',content );
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando jQuery e [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings) você pode fazer algo como o seguinte:

```
var cardComponent = (cardData) => ('
  <div class="col s12 m7">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-image">
        <img src="`${cardData.imagePath}`">
        <span class="card-title">`${cardData.imagePath}`</span>
        </div>
      <div class="card-action icone-meu-cartao">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>')

# Quando obtiver o response do cadastro você executa o seguinte:
$('.corpo-cartoes').append(
  cardComponent(response.data)
)
```

Ou uma outra dica, não sei qual o teu grau de familiaridade com Js, mas acho uma boa conhecer o Vue, na versão simplificada dele você já consegue componentizar facilmente, de uma olhada nesse [curso gratuíto](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=07-TvnH7XNo&list=PLcoYAcR89n-qq1vGRbaUiV6Q9puy0qigW).

Answer (score 0):

Pensando em melhorias de código, pesquisei e também da pra fazer com `append`:

```
$(".listagem").append(
                    `<div class="row" id="corpo-cartoes">
                        <div class="col s12 m7" style="width: 100%;">
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-image">
                                    <a href="cartao.html#${id}"><img src="${capa}"></a>
                                    <span class="card-title">${nome}</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-action icone-meu-cartao">
                                    <a href="#"><i class="material-icons">code</i></a>
                                    <a href="#"><i class="material-icons">crop_free</i></a>
                                    <a href="#"><i class="material-icons">visibility</i></a>
                                    <a href="cadastro-cartao.html#${id}"><i class="material-icons btn-editar">edit</i></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>`
                );
```

Então exclui o código acima do HTML e deixei só uma div para ir populando dentro dessa div.